# Mysql statement to select distinct rows from two columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I'm trying to write a mysql statement that pulls only unique messages from my chat system.
There is a to_id and a from_id. I want to pull one row from every conversation.

The problem is if there is a row with
    to_id = 1 
    from_id = 2 
and another row with 
    to_id = 2
    from_id = 1
I want both of these rows to be treated as the same.

The statement I came up with is "SELECT * FROM chat_messages GROUP BY to_id,from_id ". This works except for the situation I mentioned above.

Another attempt I made was using "SELECT DISTINCT least(to_id,from_id) as value1, greatest(to_id,from_id) as value2 from chat_messages ".

This returns what I need but I do not know how to get the rest of the information from the row like the message, timestamp etc. It only gives me value1 & value2 which are the to_id & from_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the expressions in the second query for the GROUP BY of the first query:

```
SELECT * FROM chat_messages GROUP BY LEAST(to_id,from_id), GREATEST(to_id,from_id)
```

Comment: @hunijkah: My answer probably warrants a note. The example query relies on a MySQL-specific extension to GROUP BY behavior. The statement will return an error in MySQL if the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled. A query of this form would return an error in a RDBMS other than MySQL (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, Teradata, DB2, et al.)

Answer (score 0):

If second query returns what you expect, then below query returns rest information:

```
SELECT *
FROM chat_messages t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(to_id, from_id) AS value1,
        GREATEST(to_id, from_id) AS value2
    FROM chat_messages
) t2 ON t1.to_id = value1 AND t1.from_id = value2;
```